# spring elastic search repository wont't store data

Tags: spring, scala, elasticsearch

I'm having a very odd problem, I'm basically trying to store an object in elastic search using springboot and repositories and for some reasons my objects are never getting persisted.

This is done, using scala

**case class:**

```
 @Document(collection = "SPECTRUM")
      @org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "spectrum", `type` = "spectrum", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
  case class Spectrum(
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   biologicalCompound: Compound,
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   chemicalCompound: Compound,
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   predictedCompound: Compound,
                   @(Indexed@field)
                   deleted: Boolean,
                   @(Id@field)
                   id: String,
                   lastUpdated: String,
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   metaData: Array[MetaData],
                   score: Score,
                   spectrum: String,
                   splash: Splash,
                   submitter: Submitter,
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   tags: Array[Tags],
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   authors: Array[Author]
                 )

}
```

**repository**

```
@Repository("spectrumElasticRepository")
trait ISpectrumElasticRepositoryCustom  extends ElasticsearchRepository[Spectrum, String]  with     SpectrumElasticRepositoryCustom{    
  def findByBiologicalCompoundInchiKey(inchiKey: String) : java.util.List[Spectrum]
}
```

**test code**

```
  getRepository.deleteAll()
  assert(getRepository.count() == 0)

      s"we should be able to store our data" in {
        for (spectrum <- exampleRecords) {
          val result = getRepository.save(spectrum)
          assert(result.isInstanceOf[Spectrum])
        }

    assert(getRepository.count() == 58)

        val data:Iterable[Spectrum] = getRepository.findAll()
      }
```

once the test code hits this line

```
            val data:Iterable[Spectrum] = getRepository.findAll()
```

it causes the following exception

```
failed to map source [ {}] to class Spectrum
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to map source [ {}] to class Spectrum
```

and looking at the elastic search server directly

```
localhost:9200/spectrum/_search
```

it looks like no data is actually attached to any of the reported hits

```
  {
    "_index": "spectrum",
    "_type": "spectrum",
    "_id": "AVNhcpHjnm4IHnHomcXj",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {}
  },
```

since source is empty.

any ideas what causes this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to scala.

Once it's ensured that every property to be stored in the elastic search database is indexed with

**@BeanProperty**

like here

```
  @Document(collection = "SPECTRUM")
  @org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "spectrum", `type` = "spectra", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
  case class Spectrum(
                   @BeanProperty
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   biologicalCompound: Compound,
                   @BeanProperty
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   chemicalCompound: Compound,
                   @BeanProperty
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   predictedCompound: Compound,
                   @BeanProperty
                   @(Indexed@field)
                   deleted: Boolean,
                   @BeanProperty
                   @(Id@field)
                   id: String,
                   lastUpdated: String,
                   @BeanProperty
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   metaData: Array[MetaData],
                   @BeanProperty
                   score: Score,
                   @BeanProperty
                   spectrum: String,
                   @BeanProperty
                   splash: Splash,
                   @BeanProperty
                   submitter: Submitter,
                   @BeanProperty
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   tags: Array[Tags],
                   @(Field@field)(`type` = FieldType.Nested)
                   authors: Array[Author]
                     )

}
```

It works fine and persists this object.

Obviously this is so ugly that it makes you wonder if there are better alternatives out there or it would make sense to write a scala aware wrapper.

Alternativly, you could overwrite the utilzied object mapper and entity impl, with one of your own choosing. This could be done like this in your configuration class.

```
  @Autowired
  val objectMapper:ObjectMapper = null

  @Bean
  def elasticsearchTemplate: ElasticsearchOperations = {
    new ElasticsearchTemplate(client,new EntityMapperImpl(objectMapper))
  }

  @Bean
  def client: Client = {
    val client = new TransportClient()
    val address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(hostname, port)
    client.addTransportAddress(address)

    client
  }

  class EntityMapperImpl(val mapper: ObjectMapper) extends EntityMapper {

    override def mapToString(`object`: scala.Any): String =     mapper.writeValueAsString(`object`)

    override def mapToObject[T](source: String, clazz: Class[T]): T =     mapper.readValue(source, clazz)
  }
```

And the exact configuration for the object mapper would look like

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper

mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

//required, in case we are provided with a list of value
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
mapper
```

which just needs to be registered as bean somewhere